# Defining the Laskowski Tri-Optimal in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm fairly new to the world of GIS software and I'm trying to project the Laskowski Tri-Optimal projection in QGIS. It has a proj.4 definition (`+proj=lask`), but no parameters are listed for it on spatialreference. I did find one website that used the string

`+proj=lask +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m`

but even this gave me the error "the proj4 definition is not valid" when entered into QGIS's CRS menu. I've successfully entered other projections, so I'm fairly certain my issue isn't a procedural one with the definition menu. Is it possible that QGIS or even GDAL don't support the Laskowski?

Comment: as far as I know qgis needs an inverse projection too. exists an inverse projection for Laskowski Tri-Optimal in the proj4. library??